# How can I change where the vertices are located on a curve using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

How can I change where the vertices are located on a curve using geometry nodes?

`Example:`  I have a curve line of **32mm** and I want the vertices located at the points of
**0,1,2,3,5,8,13 (mm)** (close to the Fibonacci sequence)

or

A curve line of **22mm** and I want the vertices located at the points
**0,3,8,11 (mm)**

The reason for this is I want to cut or place objects along the line at specific / given points.  Is there a better way of doing this?

[image: img1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would do it like this:

[image]

you can put the values directly into the nodes. Might be a bit tedious, but i think it is even faster than the repeat zone.

---

and here the more "sophisticated" version:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Secretly ... I thought that this, was amazing. lol. There was no reason to do any mathematics what so ever because the question only gave constant values that would have contradicted each other if we made them adjustable.

Answer (score 2):

It's always good to find an analytical expression for your sequence if you can, and, despite being the canonical example to teach recursion to programmers, the Fibonacci numbers [have one](https://www.lehigh.edu/%7Egi02/math163/inductnotes.pdf):

$$   \frac{ 1}{\sqrt 5}  \left(\frac{ 1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n $$

..  rounded to the nearest integer.

[image]

.. so you don't need the incremental calculation

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oops, I can't count brackets, Sorry.